# How can I access a dictionary in its own class/context to define a method?

Tags: javascript, class, reference

A toned-down example is this class, inheriting from `PublishableAction` (to provide the static `.viewController()` function as well as other methods which is used where the `// ...` is):

```js
class Action extends PublishableAction {

  static actionSelector = {
    buttonCommit: Symbol()
  };

  // This part still works as intended, accessing 'Action':
  static buttonSession = Action.viewController({
    perform: Action.actionSelector.buttonCommit
  });

  // ... but here's the issue:
  // ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Action' before initialization
  [Action.actionSelector.buttomCommit]() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

I have already tried using `[this.actionSelector.buttonCommit]()` and `[this.constructor.actionSelector.buttonCommit]()`, both not having any effect on the outcome.

How can I fix the `ReferenceError` without having to move `Action.actionSelector` to the global scope?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a weird pattern what you are trying to achieve. But maybe have a "methods" getter and return there every callable method that rely on actionSelector?

```js
class Action extends PublishableAction {

  static actionSelector = {
    buttonCommit: Symbol()
  };

  // This part still works as intended, accessing 'Action':
  static buttonSession = Action.viewController({
    perform: Action.actionSelector.buttonCommit
  });

  get methods() {
    return {
      [Action.actionSelector.buttonCommit]: function() {
        //...
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Than you can call `(new Action()).methods[Action.actionSelector.buttonCommit]()`